# `E492: Not an editor command` error only when opening file, but not when using :so %

Tags: vimrc, line-numbers, command

I have the following in my vimrc:

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'https://github.com/vim-scripts/RltvNmbr.vim'
call plug#end()

set number
RltvNmbr
```

When I type `:so %` while in my vimrc, it will turn on the relative line numbers with no error message.

However if I `:q` and reopen that same vimrc, I get:

```
E492: Not an editor command: RltvNmbr
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I was under the understanding that opening a file in vim automatically sources the vimrc. Thus I do not understand why I get the above error when opening a file in vim, but not when manually sourcing the vimrc.

Comment: No, plugins are sourced after your init scripts. Check the order in `:h startup` or check the output of the `:scriptnames` command. So perhaps you need to use an `VimEnter` autocommand to call the `RltvNmbr` command?

Comment: That's good to know! I did try `au VimEnter RltvNmbr` but that didn't seem to do anything. I have other plugin-related commands being executed after my `call plug#end()` and those don't seem to be causing any problems...

Comment: it should be `au VimEnter * RltvNmbr`

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you very much stranger! Edit: How come this command failed but other plugin-related commands worked following my call to `call plug#end()`?

Comment: @brianxk that depends on what those commands were. User commands would suffer the same problem, but calling autoload functions or setting variables probably won’t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Christian Brabandt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/71/christian-brabandt) pointed out, the plugin was being sourced after the vimrc when opening the vimrc from scratch (vs. `:so %` while the vimrc is still open).

Changing:

```
RltvNmbr
```

to:

```
au VimEnter * RltvNmbr
```

did the trick.